# How do I add global multilingual support to a web page and is it still relevant?

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, next.js, multilingual

I am currently working on a [simple landing page](https://soschool.site) and since the project is based in Luxembourg, visitors will appreciate French, German, Luxembourgish and Portuguese versions of the content in addition to the current English.

How do I deal with routing visitors to their preferred language? (Is there a way to detect the language their OS is running in?)

Also, how will having the page in different languages affect the structure of the page? (Should I use a database to serve the right text or should I just have multiple versions of the page and route using top level folders like `https://soschool.site/en` or even using subdomains like `https://en.soschool.site`)

**Fyi**: I am using next.js (`create-next-app`) and hosting on Vercel.

**On another note**: since most browsers are planning on implementing or have already introduced native translation, should I still be looking into working with multiple languages at all?

Comment: Checkout next-i18next lib

Comment: @felixmosh thank you, seems like an easy-to use solution